# Classic Shell's "Shut Down..." button is missing

Tags: shell-extensions

I use [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.net/) shell extension on my Windows 8 machines and on some of them the "Shut Down..." button is missing. Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: Are these PCs connected to an Active Domain by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes they are.

Comment: It is possible to hide/disable the Shutdown button with a group policy, verify that isn't the case, after you have verified the Shutdown button entry is actually enabled.  While the shutdown button is not on the start menu on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 it does exist on the Start Screen which means the option to shutdown the machine could be disabled.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound, no group policy enforces this. Verified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### On some of them the "Shut Down..." button is missing

You have "Don't display this item" selected for "Shutdown".

To fix this:

1. Right click the "Start" button and select "Settings".
2. Select the "Special Items" tab.
3. In the "Shutdown" section select either "Display as a link" or "Display as a menu" as appropriate.
4. Click "OK".

[image]

If you are using Remote Sessions you will also have to enable "Show Shutdown during remote sessions":

1. Right click the "Start" button and select "Settings".
2. Select the "Main Menu" tab.
3. Scroll down and enable "Show Shutdown during remote sessions".
4. Click "OK".

[image]

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill, I changed it to "Display as a link", however it did not change anything. Still do not see it.

Comment: @myroslav Then see Ramhound's comment on the question.

Comment: @myroslav By the way, your question screenshot shows "Display as menu" **not** "Display as link".

Comment: That was the original screenshot, and it was "Display as menu" originally, however I did try as you advised to change it to "Display as link" with no result.

Comment: @myroslav Are you using "Remote Sessions"?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. I do remote login to this machine. This particular machine is a virtual one and I access it by remotely logging in to it.

Comment: @myroslav See updated answer and enable "Show Shutdown during remote sessions"